# Checking if a user made a commit to Github using API on a given day

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to build an app to track GitHub "Streaks" (How many days in a row a user has committed to GitHub.) I'm trying to use the GitHub API to do this, but I can't figure out where.

If I can't pull back the streak, if I could find a way to see if they had committed on a given day (like yesterday) I could recursively determine the streak by continuing to check the previous day until there wasn't a commit.

I can find details about a specific commit https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

And I can retrieve data for a single user:
https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user

But I can't seem to find how to query the API to determine if the user made a commit on a given day.

Comment: I see there are several "date" fields in the response coming from https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/. Couldn't you use that ones?

Comment: I think I would need the `owner` and the `repository` in order to do that? `/repos/:owner/:repo/commits` I don't have a specific repo I'm looking for, I'm just curious if they have made any commit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using the GitHub Search Commits API for this. For example, to find the commits for user `km-poonacha` on `2017-08-28` you can make the following request.

`curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview' \https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:km-poonacha+author-date:2017-08-28`

Ref. [Searching commits](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-commits/)

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to just get back the `"total_count": 12,` so that I don't get the additional payload of all commits since I don't care about them?

Comment: i think the best way to restrict the payload is to use `&per_page=1` parameter and restrict the number of search results to be shown to its lowest value "1". I am not too sure, but i dont think you can just get the `total_count` parameter.

Comment: That makes sense, it's not a huge payload, so it's not the end of the world, it's just much larger than needed.