# What is the best way to get all commits for many users/organizations using the GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to get the commit activity for all the repositories from a user or organization using the GitHub API.

Currently the way I am solving the issue is:

1. List all the repos for a giving user (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories)
2. For each repo, get the commit activity by calling the commit activity (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-last-year-of-commit-activity-data)

The problem I run into is that using this method, [I quickly run to the request limit set by GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) (5000 requests per hour) since I have 1000+ users or organizations to look up.

So I am wondering if there's any other way to do this other than using 5000/hr and moving on to the next batch after 1 hour.

Comment: You my want to use GitHub Search Commits API . Maybe this has the answer to your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855484/checking-if-a-user-made-a-commit-to-github-using-api-on-a-given-day . The only problem is GitHub search restricts the number of search results to 1000. So you may need to include filters so that you are sure that the number of results is <1000 and then iterate over the filter used.